# Lumen API return all data as string after transfer to another Host server

Tags: laravel, boolean, response, lumen

I have Lumen API project with MySQL database work fine on hostgator, I transferred all project and database to A2Hosting I get problem with returned data, all data type returned is string, I have problem with boolean data returned, how can I solve it?

```
public function getMenuItems($menu_name)
{
    $menu=Menu::where('title',$menu_name)->first();
    
    if($menu){
        $langs = Language::select('id','name','surname')->where('menu_id',$menu->id)->get();
        $colors=Color::select('primary','secondary','primary_font','secondary_font')->where('menu_id',$menu->id)->first();
        $categories= Category::select('id','title','active','rank')->orderBy('rank')->where('menu_id',$menu->id)->where('active',true)->with('Name')->with('Note')->with('Items.Sub')->get();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            foreach ($cat->items as $item) {
                $item->ItemPrice;
                $item->name=$item->Name;
                foreach ($item->sub as $sub) {
                    $sub->name=$sub->Name;
                    $sub->SubPrice;
                }
            }
        }
        
        $info=Menu::select('active','fb','insta','youtube','snap','address','phone','welcome')->where('title',$menu_name)->first();
        return ["message"=>"success","data"=>$categories,"langs"=>$langs,"colors"=>$colors,"info"=>$info];
    }
    
    return ["message"=>"failed","data"=>[]];
    
}
```